# Magento 2 get custom attribute values from products collection

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I am trying to get the custom attribute vales from products collection as like below code but i didn't get attribute values.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
             $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
                                                ->addAttributeToSelect('cb_city');
             $collection = $productCollection->create()
                                             ->addAttributeToSelect('cb_city')
                                             ->load();
             print_r($collection);
```

Comment: try with print_r($productCollection->getData())

Comment: @Rakesh , i tried that

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                 $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

                 $collection = $productCollection->create()
                                                 ->addAttributeToSelect('sku');

                 print_r($collection->getData());
i tried like this but i didn't get collection based on attribute

Answer (score 4):

You can use following code for return collection base on particular attribute, here $cb_city is a value based on which you want to filter-

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $prodCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $prodCollection->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('cb_city',$cb_city)
        ->load();
        return $collection;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the collection with below script

```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
             $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
             $collection = $productCollection->create()
                                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                             ->load();
             echo "<pre>";
             print_r($collection->getData());
```